# Missing margins in .eps format

Tags: graphics, ieeetran, eps

I gave figure in Matlab-R2014a. I am using matlabfrag(.) to convert it into .eps format. My problem is that when I use \includegraphics{myfig}, margins get cropped. I tried using scale to see if size of myfig is too big for columns (I am using documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}) right now. 
This problem persists with print -deps epsFig too.

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22063/how-to-fix-eps-with-incorrect-bounding-box

Comment: Or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178745/matlab-plot-alignment-in-latex